# Send status to Facebook from Windows phone 7 silverlight application. What do I need?

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

How do I perform this?
I'm making a funny little notepad application where you should be able to send your notes to your Facebook account, as a status.

My question more directly is: Where do I find code so I login to "Facebook-write status page"?
And how do I implement it in this silverlight application? Can I use html/Javascript for this maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a project at http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ which lots of people have used to integrate Facebook functionality into their Windows Phone 7 apps.

Comment: Thank you. Ill check that in!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use javascript or html for this.

Facebook has an API that you can use by sending web requests from your application to facebooks servers. The process is not straight forward, so you should check out the documentation here: https://developers.facebook.com/search?q=API

There is an open source C# based API available here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/395 It may be easier to use than doing web requests yourself.

Comment: That C# SDK is dead.  No commits since July and no response to any bugs or roadmap update requests.  Or did you mean http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/ ? That is the C# Facebook SDK in active development and use.